# Loop through the results of a query

Tags: mysql

The query lists a bunch of Student IDs. I would like to somehow add a for loop into my query that will insert rows into another table for the count of the listed IDs.

This query list the student IDs:

```
SELECT ss.studentID
FROM schedule_students ss
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON ss.scheduleID  = a.scheduleID 
                       AND ss.studentID = a.studentID
                       AND a.status = 1
WHERE ss.scheduleID = '6004'
  AND a.studentID IS NULL
```

Then this query should run in a loop of the length of the output above:

```
INSERT INTO attendance (timestamp, status, studentID, scheduleID)
VALUES (NOW(), '0', '1002', '6004')
```

But the studentID and scheduleID should be given as "a variable" from the query above.

P.S The query above was suggested by another member of SO as an answer on another issue.

Comment: Check INSERT INTO table (fields...) SELECT... syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the select query directly to insert into your table.

```
insert into attendance (timestamp, status, studentID, scheduleID)
SELECT NOW(), 0, ss.studentID, ss.scheduleID
FROM schedule_students ss
LEFT JOIN attendance a 
  ON ss.scheduleID  = a.scheduleID 
 AND ss.studentID = a.studentID
 AND a.status = 1
WHERE ss.scheduleID = '6004'
  AND a.studentID IS NULL
```